# MS SQL: первичный ключ

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Здравствуйте.

Как можно создать PK из нескольких столбцов в MS SQL? И еще если можно: посоветуйте какой-нибудь справочник именно по проектированию баз, если такой есть (где бы по возможности было минимум необходимой теории для правильного проектирования баз).

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Что-то на примере этого:

```
Create table dbo.Table
(
    area1 smallint not null identity(1,1),
    area2 nchar(15) not null,
    area3 nchar(15) not null, 
    area4 nchar(15) not null,
    constraint PK_Table primary key (area1, area2, area3)
)
Go
```

P.S. за ключ отвечает строка **`constraint PK_Table primary key (area1, area2, area3)`**, всё остальное, так, оффтопик...

Answer (score 0):

...PRIMARY KEY (c1, c2, c3...) первой ставится колонка с наивысшей селективностью (наибольшим разнообразием) данных. И далее - в порядке убывания селективности.